# Variable inside double qoutes in onclick function

Tags: javascript, php

Hi guys i have gone through many questions discussing about variable inside double qoutes.But i don't know why those are not workin for me..
My situation is this

```
onclick="cBack(this.form,{$pageurl},{$token})"
```

I have this kind of code inside my page..when clicking the button it calls a function.but in my case it is not working.it shows a reference error in my console..

my callback function

```
function cBack(frm,pageurl,token)
  {

    pageurl=pageurl.trim(); 
    frm.method="post";
    frm.action=pageurl+'?gtoken='+token;
    frm.submit();  

}
```

Help me solving this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$pageurl` and `$token` are strings and need quotes like this:

```
onclick="cBack(this.form,'{$pageurl}','{$token}')"
```

---

With plain PHP and no templating engine:

```
onclick='cBack(this.form,<?php echo json_encode($pageurl) ?>, <?php echo json_encode($token) ?>)'
```

Notice I switched to single quotes, because json_encode will use double quotes. This produces save (means encoded) JavaScript parameters regardless of the content of your variables.

Comment: i got a url part like this /%7B$pageurl%7D?gtoken={$token} when using it

Comment: Oh, I was thinking that `{}` are the insert methods of your templating engine.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use inline event handlers. I would have an element like this:

```php
echo '<button data-page-url="' . $pageurl . '" data-token="' . $token . '">Do something</button>';
```

And in the JavaScript code, register an event listener to all elements that have a `data-page-url` attribute:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelector('[data-page-url]')).forEach(function (element) {
  element.addEventListener('click', cBack.bind(
    null, 
    element.form, 
    element.getAttribute('data-page-url'),
    element.getAttribute('data-token')
  ));
});
```